# Customize toaster from react-toastify

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, toast, react-toastify

I'm using this toaster, it works fine but I'm struggling to change it's style.

This is my code so far:

```
  import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
  import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  
  function App(){
    const notify = () => toast("Thanks! We saved your changes.!");

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={notify}>Notify!</button>
        <ToastContainer 
          className="toaster-container"
          position="top-right"
          autoClose={111111100}
          hideProgressBar={true}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover/>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I want to make it look like this:

[image]

Added a css class, (`className="toaster-container"`) I can see it in inspect mode, it is the container that has a div, which has another div inside and there is the actual toaster.

I can change the text but cannot make bold only a part of it like in the above picture neither to add an icon there.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you can pass JSX into the `toast` function so you can this to break up and style your inner design in combination with using css to run-over the outer toast css. This will also allow you to insert the icon wherever you like in this inner markup.  Something like this:

```
const notify = () =>
    toast(
      <div style={{ height: "100%", borderLeft: "5px solid green" }}>
        {/* insert your icon here */}
        <span style={{ fontWeight: "bold", color: "#000" }}>Success</span>{" "}
        Default address update
      </div>
    );
```

Check out [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-68212770-df619?file=/src/App.js) to see how you can play around with the JSX and the main css (style.css) file in order to get something close to what the screenshot you shared.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling for some time on this, I found the solution in docs.

```
const notify = () =>    
  toast(<MyComponent title={title} description={description} />);
);
```

That way it appliess all style of your component

https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/render-what-you-want

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but maybe I can help someone.

This is working on `react-toastify 8.2.0` with `react 16.9.0`.

First, I use css files for override styles:

```
.Toastify__toast-container {
  z-index: 1200 !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .Toastify__toast-container > .Toastify__toast:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 0.5em !important;
  }
}

.Toastify__toast-theme--colored.Toastify__toast--info {
  background-color: #104eb2 !important;
}

.Toastify__toast-theme--colored.Toastify__toast--success {
  background-color: #18cc48 !important;
}

.Toastify__toast-theme--colored.Toastify__toast--warning {
  background-color: #fcc52c !important;
}

.Toastify__toast-theme--colored.Toastify__toast--error {
  background-color: #FE685E !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px){
  .Toastify__toast-container--bottom-left {
    bottom: 3.5em !important; 
  }
}
```

You can see the style you need in [How to style - react-toastify](https://fkhadra.github.io/react-toastify/how-to-style)

Then, in the project I am working currently, we do not use css files too much, usually we use `makeStyles` hook from `material-ui`, so I did something like this:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import React from 'react';
import { toast, ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';

const CustomToastContainer = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <ToastContainer
      className={({ defaultClassName }) =>
        clsx(defaultClassName, classes.toastContainer)
      }
      toastClassName={({ type, defaultClassName }) =>
        clsx(defaultClassName, classes[type])
      }
      rtl={false}
      autoClose={3000}
      pauseOnHover
      position={toast.POSITION.BOTTOM_LEFT}
      theme="colored"
      limit={3}
      pauseOnFocusLoss
      newestOnTop
    />
  );
};

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  toastContainer: {
    zIndex: 1200,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(theme.breakpoints.values.sm)]: {
      bottom: '3.5em !important'
    },
    '& > .Toastify__toast:not(:last-child)': {
      marginBottom: '0.5em !important'
    }
  },
  success: {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.success.main} !important`
  },
  info: {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.primary.main} !important`
  },
  error: {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.error.main} !important`
  },
  warning: {
    backgroundColor: `${theme.palette.warning.main} !important`
  }
}));
```

`clsx(defaultClassName, classes.toastContainer)` is equivalent to concat `defaultClassName` with your own style classes, e.g. `${defaultClassName} ${classes.myClass}`.

`defaultClassName` is the variable which store the default styles mentioned on the link aboved, so, is like override them. I used `!important` in my `makeStyle` styles, but I do not sure if is really necessary. So, you can try.